# How to use floatformat in a centralized way in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

In my project I'm asking the user for some measures, prices and weights. I want to store data as a two decimal value. I guess I should be using DecimalField instead of FloatField, because I don't need much precision.

When I print values in my templates, I don't want zero non significant decimals to be printed.

**Examples:**

*10.00 should show simply 10*

*10.05 should show 10.05*

I don't want to use floatformat filter in every template I display the value, too many places. So I was wondering if there is some way to affect the value rendered for all the application, in a centralized manner.

Thanks

Comment: In `10.00` how do you know if the `.00` is significant or not?   "zero non significant decimals" presumes someone has declared what's significant.  How is that going to be specified?

Comment: significant in the mathematical way of numbers. decimals zeros don't matter, that's what I mean with non significant decimals. I don't want zeros to be displayed if the don't change anything.

Comment: @maraujop: "don't change anything" is a judgement that a person makes.  It's a matter of definition.  2.0 is **not** the same as 2.  The digit may be significant because an engineer needs to know the accuracy of the measurement.  You can't randomly drop trailing zeros.  You need to define how many zeros are significant first, then you can drop extra zeros that are not significant.

Comment: I'm not saying that Django should randomly drops zeros. I'm simply asking if there is a centralized way to ask Django to do it. Because this time I don't care about trailing zeros, I simply don't need them.

Comment: @maraujop: Why aren't you using integers?

Comment: Because I need decimals, when those are not zeros. If user says 10 I want 10, if user says 10.05 I want 10.05. I think it is normal that I want to render decimals to users in a web application, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with the answer to this question and posted it in my blog:
http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/2156476872/django-positivenormalizeddecimalfield

I hope somebody finds it useful

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the django plugin [Humanize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/) ?

You might find there what you're looking for.

**Edit**

Your are right, *humanize* filters don't do the job here.
After digging around the django built-in filters and tags I couldn't find anything that solves your issue. Therefore, I think you need a custom filter for this. Something like ...

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def my_format(value):
    if value - int(value) != 0:
        return value
    return int(value)

register.filter('my_format',my_format)
my_format.is_safe = True
```

And in your django template you could do something like ...

```
{% load my_filters %}
<html>
<body>
{{x|my_format}}
<br/>
{{y|my_format}}
</body>
</html>
```

For values `x` and `y`, `1.0` and `1.1` respectively that would show:

```
  1
  1.1
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I know the plugin and I don't see how it can help me.

Comment: @maraujop you're right. I think you need a custom filter for this. See answer new edition.

Comment: Thanks msalvadores for your effort, but I think there is a built-in filter tag called floatformat which already doest the work. My problem is that I don't want to edit all my templates, to add a filter every time I render those values. That is more than a 300 times. I could do a grep | sed, but I'm looking for a centralized solution, that doesn't imply changing the templates, adding filters, tags or context processors.

Answer (score 0):

How about a property in the model in such way that:

```
_weight = models.DecimalField(...)
weight = property(get_weight)

def get_weight(self):
    if self._weight.is_integer():
        weight = int(self._weight)
    else:
        weight = self._weight
    return weight
```